# Can I make vim change its cursor behavior?

Tags: vim, cursor

I've been using vim for a few years as a secondary editor but for various reasons, I find myself using it more and more even when my primary editor is available. One problem that has always bugged me about `vim`, and that keeps me from using it more, is the way it handles cursor placement. The cursor can only be *on* a character, rather than *between* characters, as would be the case with any editor created since 1984.

For just one example of why this is a problem, if I want to delete the last word on a line, I hit `$` to go to the end of the line, and then `db` to delete backward. This leaves a character to delete, because `$` didn't *really* go to the end of the line, it went ***to the last character of the line***, and `db` deleted only what was *before* the current character. The problem isn't that I have to type an extra character, it's the extra thought involved in doing what ought to be simple, which distracts my attention away from what I'm actually trying to accomplish.

It seems to me that the more modern idea cursor placement is in every way superior, and I'd like to switch `vim` to use that approach. I'm sure some hard-core `vim` fans will disagree with my view on that, but since one of the standard arguments for `vim`'s superiority is its infinite configurability:

- **can it deliver in this case?**
- **Can `vim` be made to place the cursor *between* characters?**

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `Insert` mode or missing the point of `normal` mode.  I'd do `$daw` or `$bdw` to delete the last word on a line in normal mode.  In `Insert` mode I would do `A<Ctrl-w>`.

Comment: See also [similar question on SU](http://superuser.com/q/242156/92173).

Comment: For the record, as someone who's frightened by the very idea of a netherworld "between characters", the correct key sequence to delete the last word on the current line is `$bD`

Comment: @AlanCurry: thanks, I try that.  I'd rather adapt `vim` to my brain and habits, but if that fails...

Comment: @jw013: I'm not sure how `Insert` mode would make this easier or faster.  In insert mode I'd have to hit the delete (or backspace on PCs) key repeatedly.  If I were deleting several words this would be extremely inefficient.  In more modern editors (and I *don't* mean to use that word as a snide put-down to `vim`--I fully realize that `vim`'s modal system is awesome in its own ways) this is handled efficiently by double-clicking a word and dragging the mouse to select other words.  But since `vim` requires adapting to its modal system, it should provide a way to do this well in `Normal` mode.

Comment: @jw013: thanks for the suggestions, though.  I'll try them.

Comment: @iconoclast You can use `CTRL-W` to delete words in `Insert` mode.  `:help i_CTRL-W`

Comment: @jw013: ahh, yes, true.  It's kind of ironic to use emacs keybindings within `vi`(m), though, and when I do it I kind of feel like I'm drinking a mixture of milk and orange juice!

Comment: The spirit of vi (and I use vim because it's a vi, not because it's "infinitely configurable") is that the farther your fingers move from the home row, the more time you've lost. `$bD` or any of the other suggestions are much less effort than reaching for the mouse to double-click something. Wanna learn it properly, unplug your mouse.

Comment: @AlanCurry: yes I'm fully aware of that.  It sounds like you're assuming I'm saying something I'm not saying, but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: @AlanCurry: also, I'm fully in agreement that it's better to avoid the mouse.  I virtually never use the mouse in `vim` and virtually never use `gvim`.  But for sake of an honest comparison it should be pointed out that modern editors also have non-mouse ways of doing what I described.  I was simply mentioning that as an example of how something can be done quickly and easily following the common approach.

Comment: Well you said "efficiently" and "double-clicking" in the same sentence. That sounded weird.

Comment: Using a mouse is not ideal, but the significant inefficiencies come when you have to stop and think about how to do what you want to do.  The real thing that is precious is not a second here and there, but ***focus***.   When you lose focus you lose far more than a few seconds.

Comment: Sorry: we're getting off-topic and I don't wan this to degenerate into an argument about the merits of `vim`.  I guess we can just agree that we have different ideas of where `vim`'s strengths lie.  We both agree it's a valuable tool, I'm just not concerned with shaving seconds off operations.

Comment: From the comments so far it sounds like the answer to the question is "No, this model of cursor movement is irrevocably embedded in vim's design and cannot be changed."  Is that correct?

Comment: @iconoclast That's my conclusion too. As far as I can tell, it is impossible in vi or vim to treat all characters on a line uniformly, there is always an exception for the first or last character.

Comment: @Gilles: since you have more experience to back it up, care to offer that as an answer?  (Or is that just a provisional conclusion of yours, that you're not comfortable asserting as necessarily true?)

Answer (score 5):

You can `:set virtualedit+=onemore`, which allows you to go just past the last character. Unfortunately for you, `$` still goes to the last character; you have to cursor over to get past it. On the other hand, you can use `g$`, which normally goes to the last character of the *screen* line on a line that wraps; in `onemore` mode it also goes just past the last character of a non-wrapped line (or the last screen line of a wrapped line).

`:h 'virtualedit'` says this option can mess up scripts, but I don't know how big a risk that is in reality.